# Looking for recommendations for a syntaxhighlighter (multilanguage support if possible)

Tags: asp.net, syntax-highlighting

I do have some strings that contains programming code, like XHTML (asp.net markup), C#, C, Java and I want to display them with a syntax highlighter on my web page.

Is there a control or a JavaScript implementation for a syntaxhightlighter that supports multiple languages?
Or would you advise that I explicitly mark the code blocks (like 'this is c# code'), and use individual controls to display these several languages? Is there anything you can recommend?

I do also take recommendations for syntaxhighlighter that only support one language.

Comment: I just found http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter. Has anyone some expierence with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) ([How can I use GeSHi under ASP?](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/faq.php#q_14)).

Comment: Looks nice, but due to the fact that I need to set up PHP and need to create a virtual directory, I' try the syntaxhighlighter by alexgorbatchev first.